# UIButton is always nil in viewDidLoad()

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, viewdidload

I have added a UIButton to my ViewController in storyboard. Then I've created an IBOutlet connection for it. Then in viewDidLoad() I want to manipulate with created button but it is always nil.

```
class LeftWeekViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var weekNumberBtn: PassThroughButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var weekNumberBtnBottomSpacing: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var plusBtn: UIButton!

    var data: [String] = ["sadasd", "adgfdgfdg", "hgfhgfhgfh", "sadasd", "adgfdgfdg", "hgfhgfhgfh", "sadasd", "adgfdgfdg", "hgfhgfhgfh"]
    var sections: [String] = ["[Ma 26 Mei]", "[Di 27 Mei]", "[Wo 28 Mei]"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let calender = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let dateComponent = calender.components(.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear  | .CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear, fromDate:NSDate())
        weekNumberBtn.setTitle("\(dateComponent.weekOfYear)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        weekNumberBtn.layer.cornerRadius = weekNumberBtn.frame.height / 2
        weekNumberBtn.clipsToBounds = true
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(weekNumberBtn)
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .None

        weekNumberBtnBottomSpacing.constant = -1 * (self.tableView(self.tableView, heightForHeaderInSection: 0) - 8)

        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "LeftWeekTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "LeftWeekCell")

        var pencilImage = UIImage(named: "pencil")!
        pencilImage = resizeImage(pencilImage, size: CGSize(width: plusBtn.frame.width - 15, height: plusBtn.frame.height - 15))

        plusBtn.layer.cornerRadius = plusBtn.frame.size.height / 2
        plusBtn.clipsToBounds = true
        plusBtn.setImage(pencilImage, forState: .Normal)
        plusBtn.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
        plusBtn.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        plusBtn.layer.masksToBounds = false
        plusBtn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 15)
        plusBtn.layer.shadowRadius = 10
        plusBtn.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4

        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(plusBtn)
    }
    //...
}
```

The first weekNumberBtn that I've created in the same way is NOT nil but the second 'plusBtn' is always nil. I don't know what is wrong. Can someone help me?

**UPDATE::**

I've cleaned and rebuild my project and it throws an error that I passed wrong xib file name when creating my ViewController. I have changed xib file name and everything works.

Comment: Did you check the connection?

Comment: @anhtu Yes, here [it is](http://oi58.tinypic.com/1t24ap.jpg).

Comment: weekNumberBtn is in the same storyboard? I don't see it.

Comment: @anhtu I have created this controller via xib file, and yes these buttons are in the same file.

Comment: In your image, I don't see weekNumberBtn connection?

Comment: remove the connection and add it one more time

Comment: @anhtu [Here](http://oi59.tinypic.com/2r3zi0y.jpg) is the weekNumberBtn connection.

Comment: @bat I've tried, the same error(.

Comment: Where is plusBtn get nil? What's line?

Comment: @anhtu on this line `pencilImage = resizeImage(pencilImage, size: CGSize(width: plusButton.frame.width - 15, height: plusButton.frame.height - 15))`. But I've also checked it with `println(plusButton)` at the start of the viewDidLoad and it is nil.

Comment: try product->clean and rebuild the project

Comment: Try reconnect, then rebuild.

Comment: @anhtu and \@bat ty for your answers. I've cleaned and rebuild my project and it throws an error that I passed wronh xib file name when creating my ViewController. I curious why xCode doesn't throw this error before clean?

Comment: However, it solved my problem, I've just changed the xib filename, ty guys.

Comment: Sometime, Xcode doesn't update the change in xib. I don't know why. Maybe need to create another question.

Answer (score -1):

> Select the  Button  and Right click on it see the outlets prepely is there or not.  if connections are not available the give the outlet to tha button. even if it not working remove exist outlets And Create outlet again. put the break points and Debug it

Comment: change the button  weak propety

Comment: Just remove "weak" or add something? I've tried to remove, the same result appears.

Comment: @IBOutlet var plusButton: UIButton!

Comment: delete previous outlet create new outlet choose strong property

Comment: all outlets must have weak property, do not choose strong